# how to find number of patients and and hospitals in a city using values (group by) in django

Tags: django, orm

I'm trying to find number of patients and and hospitals in a city: for example:

> patients : 13 , hospital : A , city : London
>
> patients : 20 , hospital : B , city : NewCastle

here is my models.py

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Hospital(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="hospital")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="patients")
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(Hospital, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="patients", blank=True, null=True)
```

here is my query:

```
City.objects.values('name').annotate(patients_no=Count('patients__pk'),hospitals_no=Count('hospital__pk'))
```

but it sums number of patients with number of hospitals! is there away to achieve it please.

i have to return number of hospitals in a city, and number of patients in a hospital,
note: i dont care about the name of the hospital

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have the number of hospitals per city, as well as the number of patients per hospital? I think you should do two different queries, since it's two different unrelated results, if I understand your intentions correctly.

Something like

```
nb_patients_per_hospital = Hospital.objects.annotate(Count('patients__pk'))
nb_hospitals_per_city = City.objects.annotate(Count('hospitals__pk'))
```

Comment: Yes i know that, but i wanted do it into one query

Comment: They are unrelated results, so that's not possible. Even in pure SQL, you could not have a column with patient count and a column with hospital count side by side in the same result set, since both counts are not related in any way to each other.